# How to obtain only published entities from field collection items in database, insted I've get all entities

Tags: database, entities

I want to obtain values from field collection and put it into an array an then display it in my twig template using for loop.

```
// MYTHEME.theme

/*

    Get social media links from sql

*/
  function MYTHEME_theme_preprocess_block__socialmedia(&$variables) {


      // Get data
      $get_links = db_query('
        SELECT DISTINCT
          social_media_select.entity_id                         as social_media_id,
          social_media_select.field_social_media_select_value   as social_media_select_val,
          social_media_link.field_social_media_link_value       as social_media_link_val,
          social_media_title.field_social_media_title_value     as social_media_title_val

        FROM field_collection_item__field_social_media_select social_media_select
        JOIN field_collection_item__field_social_media_link social_media_link ON social_media_select.entity_id = social_media_link.entity_id
        JOIN field_collection_item__field_social_media_title social_media_title ON social_media_select.entity_id = social_media_title.entity_id
      ');

      foreach ($get_links as $link) {

         // store array into global drupal $variables
         $variables['social_media_links'][] = array(
            'link_id' => $link->social_media_id, 
            'selected' => $link->social_media_select_val,
            'url' => $link->social_media_link_val,
            'title' => $link->social_media_title_val,
         );
      } // endforeach   

  }
```

And in TWIG template I've use this to display all fields and it works as it should.
But there is problem becouse it shows all entities ever entered.
If I remove some social links from drupal it still shows up in my frontend and if I look into database it is still there.

How to menage to display only active-published fields from field collection item?

```
// block--socialmedia.html.twig

{% for link in social_media_links %}

<li>
    <a href="{{ link.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ link.title }}"> 
        <i class="demo-icon"></i> 
    </a>
</li>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I find out the solution, hope someone will find useful.

When you use sql to directly retreive fields/entities from drupal there is one more thing to do in order to display only active fields with latest revision.

You need to check is that particular field has recent revisions and then to display his latest revision. In oposite case it will display all fields ever made no meter if they was deleted or changed.

You need JOIN revision table as well

```
# find out revision_id and connect with node_revision
JOIN field_collection_item_revision field_revision ON social_media_select.entity_id = field_revision.item_id
JOIN node_revision__field_social_media revision ON field_revision.revision_id = revision.field_social_media_revision_id
JOIN node_field_revision ON revision.revision_id = node_field_revision.vid

# get only latest revision
JOIN node ON node.vid = node_field_revision.vid
```

So now my code now looks like this.

```
// MYTHEME.theme

/*

Get social media links from sql

*/
function MYTHEME_theme_preprocess_block__socialmedia(&$variables) {


  // Get data
  $get_links = db_query('
    SELECT DISTINCT
      social_media_select.entity_id                         as social_media_id,
      social_media_select.field_social_media_select_value   as social_media_select_val,
      social_media_link.field_social_media_link_value       as social_media_link_val,
      social_media_title.field_social_media_title_value     as social_media_title_val

    FROM field_collection_item__field_social_media_select social_media_select
    JOIN field_collection_item__field_social_media_link social_media_link ON social_media_select.entity_id = social_media_link.entity_id
    JOIN field_collection_item__field_social_media_title social_media_title ON social_media_select.entity_id = social_media_title.entity_id

    /* I've addeded this code below -------------------------------- */

      # find out revision_id and connect with node_revision
      JOIN field_collection_item_revision field_revision ON social_media_select.entity_id = field_revision.item_id
      JOIN node_revision__field_social_media revision ON field_revision.revision_id = revision.field_social_media_revision_id
      JOIN node_field_revision ON revision.revision_id = node_field_revision.vid

      # get only latest revision
      JOIN node ON node.vid = node_field_revision.vid

   /* ------------------------------------------------------ */

  ');

  foreach ($get_links as $link) {

     // store array into global drupal $variables
     $variables['social_media_links'][] = array(
        'link_id' => $link->social_media_id, 
        'selected' => $link->social_media_select_val,
        'url' => $link->social_media_link_val,
        'title' => $link->social_media_title_val,
     );
  } // endforeach
```

}